# Bluetooth not powering up for second user

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I have two users set up on my system. Because this is a media PC, I have set up the system to automatically boot to "User-A" (standard user). When I log out User-A and log in as User-B (an admin user), the Bluetooth does not automatically power up. I can manually power it up and then everything works, it's just annoying having to do so.

Is there any way to automatically power up the Bluetooth when I log out as one user and sign in as another?

Comment: What happens when you "switch users" instead of logging out of A before logging in as B?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. I performed a fresh download/install, and everything it working as expected now. I probably should have tried what you suggested first, but I was blinded by furstration.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to automatically power up the Bluetooth when I log out as one user and sign in as another?

The best answer would address the underlying reason that bluetooth is being deactivated in the first place.  However, at this time, not enough information is provided to determine this.  So the preferred answer may be different from that which is currently provided.  This post is being created as a community wiki so that others may easily make the necessary changes and additions when they are discovered.

- If no better solution is found, most desktop sessions can be configured to automatically run the command to activate bluetooth.

  ```
  rfkill unblock bluetooth
  ```